# Find a hypergeometric formula embracing three specific cases

Tags: functions, special-functions, hypergeometric-function, random-matrices

For a parameter value $a=\frac{1}{4}$, I have the result
\begin{equation}
Q(k,\frac{1}{4})=\frac{2^{-2 k-\frac{19}{4}} \Gamma \left(2 k+\frac{13}{4}\right) \,
   _3F_2\left(1,k+\frac{13}{8},k+\frac{17}{8};k+\frac{19}{8},k+\frac{23}{8};1\right)}{\Gamma \left(k+\frac{19}{8}\right) \Gamma \left(k+\frac{23}{8}\right)}.
\end{equation}
Further, for $a=\frac{1}{2}$, there is the result
\begin{equation}
Q(k,\frac{1}{2})=\frac{\Gamma \left(2 k+\frac{9}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma (2 k+5)}
\end{equation}
and for $a=1$,
\begin{equation}
Q(k,1)=\frac{4^{k+3} \Gamma \left(k+\frac{7}{2}\right)^2 \Gamma \left(k+\frac{9}{2}\right)}{\pi 
   \Gamma (k+5) \Gamma \left(2 k+\frac{13}{2}\right)}.
\end{equation}
Can a common formula $Q(k,a)$ be found to embrace these three cases? (I have many more results for larger half-integer and integer values of $a$, that hopefully such a formula would encompass too, but will not now present them.)

Comment: Does it look like you can condense it into one formula?  Consider all of the constants, the gamma functions, and the thrown in $F$ (can't remember what its called).  I don't feel these have much of a related form.  And could you be more specific on what $Q$ is?

Comment: Thanks, Simple Art! Well, the function $Q$ pertains to a quantum-information-theoretic random-matrix-theoretic topic on which I am writing a paper. Let me simply say at the moment that the parameter $a$ is essentially equal to one-half of the standard Dyson-index-parameter $\beta$ of random matrix theory. The function $Q$ gives us a "separability probability" in quantum-information-theoretic terms. For $a$ an integer, we have a rule to generate these functions. The conceit here is that there might exist a unifying ("master") formula that unites the various cases. I can give additional Q(k,a)'s

Comment: You should definitely update your question with that information, as it would extremely helpful.  I'd like to tell you that its possible to find the master formula, but sometimes the master formula isn't exactly the greatest thing.  For example, in some problems, the master formula uses a limit (calculus limit) of another variable to evaluate the general formula, and for positive integers, the limit removes a portion of the formula when we apply L'Hospital's rule and solve.  So... the obscurity of something like a limit making the simplified cases what they are can be misleading and useless.

Comment: Good luck with your paper and I hope you solve your problem.